# Hyperledger Composer System Namespaces

Tags: namespaces, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

I found the following sentence in the Hyperledger Composer Modeling language documentation about system namespaces.

Could anyone explain the meaning of the following sentence?

> If you have defined an event or transaction including an eventId, transactionId, or timestamp, you must delete the eventId, transactionId, or timestamp properties.

[Link to reference](https://hyperledger.github.io/composer/latest/reference/cto_language.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

eventId, transactionId, or timestamp properties are autmatically appended by HYperleger Fabric in the background . So if you see at the Rest loopback interface you can see there is transaction id and timestamp present there , but as a client running transaction you don't need to provide those parameters, and it will be auto filled once transaction is completed . When you will read these transaction you will be able to see the timestamp and transaction id.